# How to add Querystring parameter from Code behind using javascript in asp.net?

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, query-string

I am opening a page onClick event using javascript from code behind. But *i want to pass querystring parameter and access it on another page.*

```
string id=1;
    teammember.Attributes.Add("onclick", "window.location.href='TeamMemberDetails.aspx?Id=" + Id + "'");
```

The above code works fine!

**Now i want to append QueryString using Javascript and Access it on another page from CodeBehind.**

I Tried :

```
teammember.Attributes.Add("onclick", "window.location.href='TeamMemberDetails.aspx?Id=" + Id + "'" + "&isabout=true");
```

but it does'nt work!

How to Conditional Redirect using HTML Anchor:

```
 <a style="border: 0px none; float: left;" href="TeamMember.aspx">

            <img alt="<--" src="Images/ArrowLeft.png" style="display: inline-block; cursor: pointer;
                border: 0 none;" />
        </a>
```

In above I want to set conditional Redirect depending on Querystring Parameter?

Eg: if isabout=true then redirect to TeamMember.aspx else Other.aspx
Help Appreciated!
Thanks

Comment: ek number shekhar bhau. changla prashna aahe.

Comment: you need to wrap ID with single quotes.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have a single quote `'` within the query string. You have to change the location of the quote `'` to the end of the href string.

change this.

```
teammember.Attributes.Add("onclick", "window.location.href='TeamMemberDetails.aspx?Id=" + Id + "'" + "&isabout=true");
```

To this.

```
teammember.Attributes.Add("onclick", "window.location.href='TeamMemberDetails.aspx?Id=" + Id + "&isabout=true'");
```

Comment: thanks for reply! But this gives Javascript Error: "Unternminated String"!

Comment: I've modified my answer .. pls try it again.

Comment: Thanks this works! Will u please reply to my second question that i have modified in existing?

Comment: It depends ... where is the check being done? on what page? is the redirect supposed to be server side or client side?

Comment: either on server side or client side its ok but should work that set..!but using Ancher tag only :) plz...?

Comment: might be better to ask another question and put this info there. if i answer the updated question here it might not make much sense for other users. Better to create a new question .. just paste the link here and i'll answer instantly.

Comment: mark your anchor tag runat server , give it an ID , now you can use this anchor from your code behind file.

Comment: Hello @scartag here is link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15675871/how-to-conditional-redirect-using-html-a-tag-depending-on-querystring-value-in