# How to conditional Redirect using HTML <a> tag depending on QueryString Value in asp.net?

Tags: asp.net, redirect, anchor, conditional-statements

I am redirecting to Teammember.aspx page with javascript from code behind.

```
teammember.Attributes.Add("onclick", "window.location.href='TeamMemberDetails.aspx?Id=" + Id + "'" + "&isabout=true");
```

When coming on TeamMemberDetails.aspx page i have an anchor tag:

```
 <a style="border: 0px none; float: left;" href="TeamMember.aspx">
    <img alt="<--" src="Images/ArrowLeft.png" style="display: inline-block; cursor: pointer;border: 0 none;" />
 </a>
```

Now, Depending on Querystring parameter i.e isabout the page must redirect.
if isabout=true then it must redirect to Memberlist.aspx page else other.aspx page using HTML Anchor Tag  (Conditional Redirect)

Answer (score 1):

put `runat="server"` attribute and find anchor tag in code behind.

```
  <a id="lnktoRedirect" runat="server">Redirect</a>
```

Code behind:

```
 if (isabout)
 {
       lnktoRedirect.HRef = "Memberlist.aspx";
 }
 else
 {
       lnktoRedirect.HRef = "other.aspx";
 }
```

Comment: thanks @Ashwini for replying! but where to write this code? as its hyperlink it doesnt have Click event

Comment: you can find anchor tag id (or hyperlink if you use) in code behind after placing runat="server", and use "href" property to assign your page.